# How to use current_post to open a new unordered list every five posts

Tags: loop

How can I add a break dynamically after 5 posts have been display to create a list of post titles?

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
          <ul>
            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom-post-type' );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $query ->have_posts() ) : $query ->the_post();
                  ?>

            <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

                <?php $query_count = $query ->current_post + 1; ?>
                <?php if ( $query_count % 5 == 0): ?>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <ul>

              <?php endif; ?> 

           <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

At the moment first 10 posts are displayed correctly with the remaining posts not being displayed. There is a empty third div element following the first 2 divs but no posts. I can't see what I've missed. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically checking `( $query->current_post + 1 ) % 5 == 0`. For the last post, where `$query->current_post` equals `9`, this also returns true, as `10 % 5` equals `0`. Thus, another closing and opening of a `div` and a `ul` is outputted.

You can prevent this by checking whether there are any posts left to display (using `$query->post_count`, the number of posts being displayed):

```
if ( $query_count % 5 == 0 && $query_count < $query->post_count )
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. The empty div is gone. Second challenge is the missing posts. I added `'posts_per_page' => 0` but the posts do not show. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using `posts_per_page => -1`? Using `posts_per_page => 0` will use the number of posts per page specified in your Reading settings.

Comment: That was it! I didn't understand that 0 was connected to Reading settings. Thanks!